# Javascript remove special characters from beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to hyphenate a string in javascript. The string is a url (e.g '/home/about/').

My current regex, is working but the output is not as desired.

If the first/last character of the string is a special character, it should be removed and instead of being changed into a hyphen.

Example:

```
    var string = '/home/about/';
    string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-').toLowerCase(); 
    // Returns -home-about- but I need home-about
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var s="/home/about/";
s.match(/[^\/]+/g).join('-'); // home-about
```

Comment: Ah, great. Only one expression, even better. Thanks!

Comment: How to remove the special character only at the end?

Answer (score 8):

`^\/` means `/` at begin and `\/$` means `/` at the end. joined them with pipe to handle both removals from the end.

```
string = string.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Then do your regex operation:

```
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Yes, this is brilliant. Thank you for the answer, also thank you for explaining the solution. Will accept as answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace use finding groups.

Where You will look for a group of any characters prefixed and postfixed with any of the special characters (its only / or some more?).

Next concatenate '-' with that new string, and You are done.